# How to insert data into a table that is on Azure SQL database and few columns are encrypted using Azure Key Vault through Airflow DAG

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, airflow, azure-keyvault

How to insert data into a table that is on Azure SQL database and few columns are encrypted using Azure Key Vault through Airflow DAG.

What should the connection string look like when using airfflow.hooks.mssql_hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your MsSQL server, using a SQL Alchemy connection string in the following format:

```
connectionString = "mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```